# TCL List or variables in SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, list, tcl

I am running into an issue trying to use a list in with orasql. Is there another way to do it? I know I could loop through using foreach and set the value to a string variable but I think it would take a lot longer with all of those little db pulls. I could also run one query but I am no DBM and I can't seem to get the query time down, it's a lot more complex than what I am laying out here and I need users to pull it as quickly as possible.
How can I do something like this:

```
orasql $DB(db) "select this from this_table"
orafetch $DB(db) {
    lappend list1 @1
}
orasql $DB(db) "select that from that_table where this in ($list1)"
orafetch $DB(db) {
    lappend that @1
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you are trying to do?

```
select that
from that_table
where this in (select this from this_table);
```

Comment: I can do it that way but it is very inefficient, because the query is complex. Also, I won't always run the first one with the second one. That is why I need the variable in the IN clause. When I have tried to do what I have above, I get an error stating something like "String literal too long" which means that sql is not using it as a list.

Comment: In general, it seems like a bad idea to pass results from the server to the application to put into a list to give back to the server.  Better to find a single query that does what you need.

Comment: Thanks for your advice. I have asked SE:DBMs to look at my query.